# C Socket Programming Server sending the same message to multiple clients

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

So Im new to socket programming.

I have a basic wordchain game which prints out if the word is correct or not (starts with the previous word's last letter).

I want this program to communicate with multiple clients, and send the message ("Correct" or "Wrong) to all the clients not only the one which sent the word in.

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int sockfd, ret;
     struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    int newSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddr;
    char lastchar = 'a';
    socklen_t addr_size;

    char buffer[1024];
    pid_t childpid;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Server Socket is created.\n");

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Bind to port %d\n", 4444);

    if(listen(sockfd, 10) == 0){
        printf("[+]Listening....\n");
    }else{
        printf("[-]Error in binding.\n");
    }


    while(1){
        newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &addr_size);
        if(newSocket < 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));

        if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
            close(sockfd);

            while(1){
                recv(newSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);

                if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
                    printf("Disconnected from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
                    break;
                }else{

                    if(buffer[0]==lastchar){
                        lastchar = buffer[strlen(buffer)-1];
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                        strcpy(buffer, "Correct!");
                    }else{          
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                        strcpy(buffer, "Wrong!");
                    }
                    send(newSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    close(newSocket);


    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 4444

int main(){

    int clientSocket, ret;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    char buffer[1024];

    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(clientSocket < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Client Socket is created.\n");

    memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("[-]Error in connection.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("[+]Connected to Server.\n");

    while(1){
        printf("Client: \t");
        scanf("%s", &buffer[0]);
        send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

        if(strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0){
            close(clientSocket);
            printf("[-]Disconnected from server.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0) < 0){
            printf("[-]Error in receiving data.\n");
        }else{
            printf("Server: \t%s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The data sent by `send` does _not_ necessarily arrive as one block. `recv` can split the data arbitrarily, and each call could only return one byte at a time in the worst case. You _have to_ to check `recv`'s return value and remember the last received data, and combine it to retrieve one entire message. Ideally, you prefix each message with the total length so the receiving end knows what to expect.

Comment: What happens using your code? It's difficult to help without this starting point. After that, I can say that after a fast check it seems that you don't keep track of accepted socket (and you never check send/receive return values! Bad!).

Comment: Unfortunately, there are really a lot of things wrong with your code. I suspect you've taken on a task that is too ambitious for your knowledge level. It seems you don't yet understand that TCP is a byte-stream protocol and are treating it like a message protocol. Get that fixed first. Then re-consider the decision to use a process for each connection because inter-process communication is harder than intra-process communication.

Comment: ... to word it differently: TCP (i.e. `SOCK_STREAM`) provides a _stream_ of bytes, with no separation between messages. Internally, TCP may split/combine data into packets of any size. TCP does _not_ provide your application with any kind of packet/block/message thing, and you have to separate the data stream into messages in your own way. Libraries like [ZeroMQ](https://zeromq.org/) do that (and more) for you.

Comment: The easiest fix may be to wrap the TCP sockets into a stdio-stream with `fdopen()` and use `fgets()/fputs()/fprintf()` and a line-based protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a connection with each client. Sockets allow bidirectional communication. So first set up a socket connection with each client, then start your game, and then you can send messages to all clients.

Comment: The question does not mention broadcasts. By spawning sub-processes, the code _does_ already communicate with each client individually.

Comment: I misused the word. Fixed it.

Comment: @BenjaminErichsen I think you missed the point; what you describe is what the OP already _does_

Comment: The code already does what you describe. The problems lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the port number every time you execute the program. Otherwise, the port will be occupied and unable to connect. The port number should above 1024 because of the first 1024 all predefined ports.

Comment: Just closing the listening socket when terminating the server is a much better idea. How is the client supposed to connect to a random port?

Comment: In the client and server code there is a static value for port need to change there manually